# Remove Automatic Page Breaks in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, row, openpyxl, page-break

I am using openpyxl in Python to write to a worksheet. I need to add page breaks to specific rows. I am able to successfully add those row breaks using this block of code:

```
page_break_rows = [44, 90, 135, 180, 226, 262]
    for row in page_break_rows:
        self.new_sheet.row_breaks.append(Break(id=row))
```

However, I cannot seem to get rid of the automatic page breaks that Excel creates, leaving me with a bunch of unnecessary pages on my worksheet. Any suggestions on how to either delete the page breaks that Excel makes or how to maybe move them to the right spots?

Comment: You can inspect the page breaks of the worksheet to see what Excel has created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours. But it seems that I found a way to solve it. Please read the following lines:

```
import xlwings as xw
app=xw.App(visible=False,add_book=False)
workbook=app.books.open('XXX.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.sheets('XXX')
worksheet.api.ResetAllPageBreaks() 
workbook.save()
app.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The key line is as this: worksheet.api.ResetAllPageBreaks(), it applies the code from vba. Some of vba codes can be used with 'api' in xlwings.

Comment: Please EDIT your other answer instead of posting again. Also please format your code correctly (I edited it for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

Hey there after a lot of google I could not find a way to delete single pagebreak since pagebreaks doesn't support del or remove or pop, but you can delete all pagebreaks by setting col.breaks to None.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).